# Network meta-analysis with three outcomes

Tags: r, metafor, network-meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis with 3 treatments (manual therapy, dry needling and placebo) and 3 outcomes (VAS, QoL and ROM, all of them are continuous variables). With `metafor` package I have `R` code to perform multivariate ma with multiple outcomes, and on the other hand, to perform a network ma with multiple treatments, but I don't know the more appropriate `R` code to combine both.

My data set looks like this:

`data <-  data.frame(study = c("Nicolas, 2022", "Nicolas, 2022", "Nicolas, 2022", "Nicolas, 2022",  "Nicolas, 2022", "Nicolas, 2022", "Nicolas, 2022", "Nicolas, 2022",  "Nicolas, 2022", "Eleuterio, 2021", "Eleuterio, 2021", "Eleuterio, 2021",  "Eleuterio, 2021", "Oliver, 2020", "Oliver, 2020", "Oliver, 2020",  "Oliver, 2020", "Oliver, 2020", "Oliver, 2020", "Camilo, 2021",  "Camilo, 2021", "Camilo, 2021", "Camilo, 2021", "Camilo, 2021",  "Camilo, 2021"), treatment = c("Manual therapy", "Dry needling", "Placebo", "Manual therapy",  "Dry needling", "Placebo", "Manual therapy", "Dry needling",  "Placebo", "Manual therapy", "Dry needling", "Manual therapy",  "Dry needling", "Dry needling", "Placebo", "Dry needling", "Placebo",  "Dry needling", "Placebo", "Manual therapy", "Dry needling",  "Placebo", "Manual therapy", "Dry needling", "Placebo"), outcome = c("VAS", "VAS", "VAS", "QoL", "QoL", "QoL", "ROM", "ROM", "ROM",  "VAS", "VAS", "QoL", "QoL", "VAS", "VAS", "QoL", "QoL", "ROM",  "ROM", "VAS", "VAS", "VAS", "QoL", "QoL", "QoL"), n = c(10, 15, 12, 10, 15, 12, 10, 15, 12, 20, 21, 20, 21, 25, 25,  25, 25, 25, 25, 32, 31, 32, 32, 31, 32), mean = c(4, 3, 6, 15, 20, 10, 120, 140, 90, 5, 3, 25, 30, 3, 6, 20,  12, 145, 100, 5, 4, 8, 23, 20, 18), sd = c(2.5, 1.3, 1.5, 3.5, 4.6, 2.8, 10.2, 8.5, 9.1, 1.3, 1.8, 6.3,  9.2, 2.1, 1.6, 5.8, 6.4, 20.3, 18.6, 2.6, 2.1, 2.3, 6.5, 7.1,  6.8))`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of a traditional frequentist model, I would suggest you to have a look at Bayesian modeling in BUGS (directly or via R)... Another approach could be applying a multivariate meta-analysis framework

Comment: Hello Giuseppe, perhaps bugsnet r package can do it? I have no experience with Winbugs or Openbugs and this r package appears to work with bugs also; many thanks!!